# How to find the Laurent series in region around a pole?

Tags: sequences-and-series, laurent-series

I am trying to find the Laurent series for $$\frac{1}{z^3(z-5)^2}$$, in the region $0<|z-5|<5$. I am not sure how to go about solving this because the region $0<|z-5|<5$ is surrounding the point $z=5$.

Another example that I encountered is $$\frac{1+z}{z(z-4)^3}$$ for $0<|z-4|<4$

How to find the Laurent series for functions of this type?

Comment: For the second one, since the below answers already lay out the meat of it, you should rewrite it as follows:
$$\frac{1+z}{z(z-4)^3}=\frac1{(z-4)^3}\left[1+\frac1z\right]$$Then $\frac1z=\frac{\frac14}{1+\frac{z-4}4}$ and binomial expand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advocate using the change of coordinates $w=z-5$, so that one is
expanding in powers of $w$. The function is now
$$\frac1{w^2(w+5)^3}.$$
We are assuming that $|w|<5$, so then
$$\frac1{(w+5)^3}=\frac{(1+w/5)^{-3}}{5^3}.$$
We can now expand $(1+w/5)^{-3}$ by the binomial theorem, as $|w/5|<1$.

Comment: Ah, good ol' binomial theorem.  Though it does simplify a bit, so perhaps you should mention that.  Also, you have $\frac1{(w+5)^2}$ when you probably meant $\frac1{(w+5)^3}$

Comment: What happens to the $1/{w^2}$  term do I just multiply it by the binomial expansion once I find it?

Comment: @gbd Yes, its just a factor to multiply in.

Comment: @gbd Indeed, it's $w^{-2}$ so very easy to manipulate!

Comment: $5^2$ in the denominator?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\frac1{z^3}&=\frac12\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\frac1 z\\&=\frac12\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\frac1{5-5+z}\\&=\frac12\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\frac{\frac15}{1-\frac{5-z}5}\\&=\frac1{10}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(5-z)^n}{5^n}\\&=\frac1{10}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n(n-1)(5-z)^{n-2}}{5^n}\\&=\frac1{10}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n(n-1)(-1)^n}{5^n}(z-5)^{n-2}\end{align}$$

Divide this by $(z-5)^2$ to get your function:

$$f(z)=\frac1{10}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n(n-1)(-1)^n}{5^n}(z-5)^{n-4}$$

Comment: Clean and beautiful. +1. Oh, and happy Easter!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Happy Easter to you too!